# list of int Log as String in java

Tags: android, arrays, string, arraylist

I have a recipe, a list of Strings and int, which they are been recognized from an image.

```
 String elementText = "";
for (Text.Element element : line.getElements()) {
                        elementText = element.getText();
                        Point[] elementCornerPoints = element.getCornerPoints();
                        Rect elementFrame = element.getBoundingBox();
                        checkObject(elementText);
```

But, when i do Log.d, i get only strings:

```
private void checkObject(Object obj) {
        if(obj instanceof Integer){
            Log.d("log int", String.valueOf(obj));
            Log.d("log int", "it's a number");
        }
        else if(obj instanceof String){
            Log.d("log string", (String)obj);
            Log.d("log string", "it's a string");

    }
}
```

10:21:40.532  D  oil  
10:21:40.532  D  it's a string

10:21:40.534  D  garlic 
10:21:40.534  D  it's a string

10:21:40.537  D  oregan 
10:21:40.537  D  it's a string

10:21:40.545  D  50 
10:21:40.545  D  it's a string

10:21:40.545  D  g 
10:21:40.545  D  it's a string

10:21:40.545  D  120 
10:21:40.545  D  it's a string

I was looking to separate them in 1 arraylist with 2 parameters, (string, int).
Do you think i need to create an arraylist instead of declaring `elementText` as string?

[image]

**Update**
I also tried this, first part of code works great `check()` with output:
22:25:56.675  D  List [1, 2, 120, 50]
function `IsInt_ByRegex` is still giving int as string:

```
private void check(String elementText){
    try{
        int num = Integer.parseInt(this.elementText);
        // is an integer!
        Log.d("LOG int", "int " + num);
        list.add(num);
        Log.d("LOG int", "List " + list); //List [1, 2, 120, 50]
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // not an integer!
    }
}
private void IsInt_ByRegex(String elementText) {

    try{
        elementText.matches("/\\{[a-zA-Z]+\\}/");
        Log.d("LOG string", "string " + elementText);
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
}
```

Output:
22:25:56.674  D  string 50
22:25:56.649  D  string red
22:25:56.649  D  string peppers
22:25:56.654  D  string 120

Comment: `element.getText()` will always return a String so u can not check type . You need to check the value . See the link above ..

Comment: Thanks. How can i check the value? i did i little dig into your link, and i try the ```matches``` method, but i still get String... see question updated.

Comment: `22:25:56.675` is not a Integer its an String .. What are you trying to do exactly ?
I suggest you should edit your question with proper details .. Some inputs and expected output .. Then only anyone can suggest something .. Right its not very clear ..